# Symfony Order table field using doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony4

I'm using Symfony 4 with Doctrine. I have tried to create a new entity which has a table field name order.

```php
class Item {

    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(name="order", type="smallint", nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\GreaterThanOrEqual(value="1", message="validators.min_value")
     */
    private $order;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotNull
     */
    private $featured;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotNull
     */
    private $enabled;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->order    = 1;
        $this->featured = false;
        $this->enabled  = true;
    }

   ...

 }
```

But when I try to save a new model relation, I get the following Error message:

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO public_items (order, featured, enabled) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params [3, 0, 1]:\n\nSQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order, featured, enabled) VALUES (3, 0, 1)' at line 1

Answer (score 2):

After Some hours of searching about the error, I have found that the ORM is not doing things well with the `order` column. Instead of using internally as `´order´` it's using as is.
So the way to define this column in the model is

```
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(name="`order`", type="smallint", nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\GreaterThanOrEqual(value="1", message="validators.min_value")
     */
    private $order;
```

Comment: Ah yes, this is a common gotcha. Doctrine does not apply escaping to keywords in queries, and this leads to an occasional obscure error if you happen to have a property with a reserved word.